# How to disallow relaying from external domains to external domains?

Tags: exchange-2003

Is there a way to disallow relaying emails from external domains, to external domains, in Exchange 2003?

Example:

`internal.com` is the only domain that this server manages.

- I want to allow emails from `internal.com` to `internal.com`.
- I want to allow emails from `internal.com` to other domains (incl. from remote locations)
- I want to allow emails from other domains to `internal.com`
- I **don't** want to allow emails from other domains to other domains

The server isn't an open relay, but by authenticating, it's still possible to send email from external domains to other external domains. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow authenticated relaying then disable authenticated relaying on the Access tab of the properties pages of the SMTP Virtual Server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still need the authenticated relaying for internal users connecting from remote locations to send from the internal domain to others (2nd scenario). I'll complete the question.

Comment: Why not have the remote users use RPC over HTTP?